# Restructuring object

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to take an object like this:

```
SortedList<string, SortedList<int, SortedList<DateTime, double>>> Data
```

and, for a given 'int' value (key of first nested sorted list), restructure it like this:

```
SortedList<DateTime, SortedList<string, double>>
```

or, better yet, this:

```
SortedList<DateTime, double[]>
```

where each 'double[]' has as many elements as there are KeyValue pairs in the SortedList.

I'm guessing Linq is the way to go, but can't figure it out.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please do not preface with C# or LINQ, that is what tags are for.

Comment: Can your top-level list have multiple key-value pairs with lists containing the same `int` as a key?

Comment: Your transformation is not possible if you use the full resolution of DateTime unless your system regularizes the inserted DateTime value somehow. Even very rapid inserts can occur on a different tick.

Comment: ... where each 'double[]' has as many elements as there are KeyValue pairs in *which* SortedList?

Comment: @JamieSee Why do you think the DateTimes have anything to do with the system clock?

Comment: What does that even mean `SortedList<string, SortedList<int, SortedList<DateTime, double>>>`? I can't even wrap my head around that.

Comment: @Jason I believe that roughly translates to "should have created a custom class or two or three."

Comment: @phoog Because a very typical date-based pattern is to use DateTime.Now when inserting to something with a date value. Because of that, I felt the need to point it out. Obviously, if an arbitrary value that limits its precision or something Like DateTime.Today is being used, this becomes less of an issue.

Comment: @JamieSee I understand.  But the starting object guarantees that each double value is associated with a unique combination of string key, int key, and DateTime key.

Comment: Thank you for the overwhelming, creative, and quick feedback!  I agree with the statement "should have created a custom class or two or three.".  Anyway, it's interesting & educational for me to understand how these solutions are constructed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

digEmAll beat me to it, but here's the second case in query comprehension syntax:

```
int desiredInt = //whatever...

var query = from pair in Data
        from pair2 in pair.Value
        where pair2.Key == desiredInt
        from pair3 in pair2.Value
        group pair3.Value by pair3.Key into grp
        select new { grp.Key, Value = grp.ToArray() };

var result = new SortedList<DateTime, double[]>(query.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

The second case is pretty neat:

```
var dateGroups = Data.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                     .ToSortedList(g => g.Key, 
                                   g => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
```

The first case instead seems wrong, I suspect it should be:

```
SortedList<DateTime, SortedList<string, double[]>>
```

If so, the code to get that is the following:

```
var dict = 
(from x in Data
 from y in x.Value
 from z in y.Value
 select new { StrKey = x.Key, IntKey = y.Key, DateKey = z.Key, Value = z.Value })
.GroupBy(x => x.DateKey)
.ToSortedList(g1 => g1.Key,
              g1 => g1.GroupBy(x => x.StrKey)
                      .ToSortedList(g2 => g2.Key,
                                    g2 => g2.Select(y => y.Value).ToArray()));
```

Where `ToSortedList` is the following extension:

```
public static class Exts
{
    public static SortedList<TK, TV> ToSortedList<TEl, TK, TV>(
        this IEnumerable<TEl> elements,
        Func<TEl, TK> keySelector, 
        Func<TEl, TV> valueSelector)
    {
        if(elements == null || keySelector == null || valueSelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("An argument of ToSortedList is null");
        var dict = new SortedList<TK, TV>();
        foreach (var el in elements)
            dict.Add(keySelector(el), valueSelector(el));
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int givenKey = ...;

  var variant1 = new SortedList<DateTime, SortedList<string, double>>(
    Data.Select(pair => new { str = pair.Key, dateValues = pair.Value[givenKey] })
    .Where(pair => pair.dateValues != null)
    .SelectMany(pair => pair.dateValues.Select(dateValue => new { pair.str, date = dateValue.Key, value = dateValue.Value }))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.date)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => new SortedList<string, double>(group.ToDictionary(triple => triple.str, triple => triple.value)))
  );

  var variant2 = new SortedList<DateTime, double[]>(
    Data.Select(pair => new { str = pair.Key, dateValues = pair.Value[givenKey] })
    .Where(pair => pair.dateValues != null)
    .SelectMany(pair => pair.dateValues.Select(dateValue => new { pair.str, date = dateValue.Key, value = dateValue.Value }))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.date)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(triple => triple.value).ToArray())
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation is not possible if you use the full resolution of DateTime unless your system regularizes the inserted DateTime value somehow. Even very rapid inserts can occur on a different tick. If you do regularize it then you can get your values as follows:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, double[]> results = (from d1 in Data
                                          from d2 in d1.Value
                                          where d2.Key == 1
                                          from d3 in d2.Value
                                          group d3 by d3.Key into d3Group
                                          select new {Key = d3Group.Key, Value = (from d4 in d3Group
                                                                                  select d4.Value).ToArray()
                                                      }).ToDictionary(element => element.Key, element => element.Value);

SortedList<DateTime, double[]> newSortedList = new SortedList<DateTime, double[]>(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Phoog's answer is good, but maybe you should consider `ILookup` instead of `SortedList`...

```
ILookup<DateTime, double> result =
(
  from pair1 in Data
  from pair2 in pair1.Value
  where pair2.Key == givenInt
  from pair3 in pair2.Value
  from theDouble in pair3.Value
  select new {theDateTime = pair3.Key, theDouble = theDouble }
)
.ToLookup(x => x.theDateTime, x => x.theDouble);
```